# Error in accessing Rapid Miner API from java program

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, rapidminer

I have a demo data that i need to cluster. The utility is supposed to send the data to rapid miner algorithm and then retrieve the result. I used Rapid Miner API to use the existing algorithms of rapid miner. However I am facing the problem using this API.

Java Class:

```
package rajeev.rapidminer.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.rapidminer.Process;
import com.rapidminer.RapidMiner;
import com.rapidminer.RapidMiner.ExecutionMode;
import com.rapidminer.operator.IOObject;
import com.rapidminer.operator.OperatorException;
import com.rapidminer.repository.IOObjectEntry;
import com.rapidminer.repository.MalformedRepositoryLocationException;
import com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryException;
import com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation;
import com.rapidminer.tools.XMLException;



public class Main {

public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException, XMLException, RepositoryException, OperatorException
{
    String rmpPath="C:/Users/rajeev-s/.RapidMiner5/repositories/Local Repository/DemoClustering.rmp";
    RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
    RapidMiner.init();
    Process process=new Process(new File(rmpPath));

    RepositoryLocation modelLocation=new RepositoryLocation("//C:/Users/rajeev-s/.RapidMiner5/repositories/Local Repository/ClusterDemoOutput");
    IOObject model=((IOObjectEntry)modelLocation.locateEntry()).retrieveData(null);

    RepositoryLocation testDataLocation=new RepositoryLocation("//LocalRepository/TestData.txt");
    IOObject testData=((IOObjectEntry)testDataLocation.locateEntry()).retrieveData(null);

    com.rapidminer.operator.IOContainer ioInput = new com.rapidminer.operator.IOContainer(new IOObject[] { model, testData });
    process.run(ioInput);
    process.run(ioInput);
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final com.rapidminer.operator.IOContainer ioResult = process.run(ioInput);
    final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("T:" + (end - start));
}
```

}

The error stack trace is:

```
Oct 25, 2013 6:28:53 PM com.rapidminer.tools.ParameterService init
INFO: Reading configuration resource com/rapidminer/resources/rapidminerrc.
Oct 25, 2013 6:28:53 PM com.rapidminer.tools.I18N <clinit>
INFO: Set locale to en.
Oct 25, 2013 6:28:54 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Property rapidminer.home is not set. Guessing.
Oct 25, 2013 6:28:54 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Trying parent directory of 'C:\Program Files\Rapid-     I\RapidMiner5\lib\launcher.jar'...gotcha!
Oct 25, 2013 6:28:54 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Trying parent directory of 'C:\Program Files\Rapid-   I\RapidMiner5\lib\rapidminer.jar'...gotcha!
Oct 25, 2013 6:29:00 PM com.rapidminer.tools.expression.parser.ExpressionParserFactory  <clinit>
INFO: Default version of expression parser registered successfully
Oct 25, 2013 6:29:06 PM com.rapidminer.parameter.ParameterTypePassword decryptPassword
WARNING: Password in XML file looks like unencrypted plain text.
Oct 25, 2013 6:29:10 PM com.rapidminer.tools.OperatorService init
INFO: Number of registered operator classes: 443; number of registered operator    descriptions: 444; number of replacements: 403
Oct 25, 2013 6:29:10 PM com.rapidminer.tools.jdbc.JDBCProperties <init>
```

WARNING: Missing database driver class name for ODBC Bridge (e.g. Access)
    Oct 25, 2013 6:29:10 PM com.rapidminer.tools.jdbc.JDBCProperties registerDrivers
    INFO: JDBC driver ca.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver not found. Probably the driver is not   installed.
    [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
    Exception in thread "main" com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryException: Requested   repository C: does not exist.
    at com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:201)
    at com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation.getRepository(RepositoryLocation.java:139)
    at com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation.locateEntry(RepositoryLocation.java:162)
    at rajeev.rapidminer.main.Main.main(Main.java:29)

When i copied the 'Local Repository'to my class path and changed the path to:

```
//Local Repository/ClusterDemoOutput
```

then following stack trace is getting generated:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryException: Requested  repository LocalRepository does not exist.
    at     com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:201)
    at  com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation.getRepository(RepositoryLocation.java:139)
    at  com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation.locateEntry(RepositoryLocation.java:162)
    at rajeev.rapidminer.main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Kindly tell me where to place the repository.

Also kindly suggest any proper blog or tutorial which explains how to use Rapid Miner algorithms from java code (the stuff i searched on google does not mention all the details)

Thanks

Comment: have you managed with it? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi andi. Ya i tried and got a working solution. I just removed the lines of the `main()` method contaning `RepositoryLocation` and the file path for `.rmp` file while creating `Process` is changed to `com.rapidminer.Process myProcess = new com.rapidminer.Process(new File("D:\\HCL\\drools\\Repository1\\Example1.rmp"));` this solution worked for me.

Comment: @andi: If you need the code i have pasted it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got a working solution for the mentioned problem. I am not sure if its the best one but it worked for me.

```
public class MinerForum {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException, XMLException,  RepositoryException, OperatorException
    {
        int[] data={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        List<Attribute> attributes=new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        String[] columns={"column1"};
        DataTable table=new SimpleDataTable("table1",columns);      
        for(int i=0;i<21;i++)
        {
            double[] value={i};
            DataTableRow row=new SimpleDataTableRow(value, i+"");
            table.add(row);
        }

        RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
        RapidMiner.init();      
        com.rapidminer.Process myProcess = new com.rapidminer.Process(new File    ("D:\\drools\\Repository1\\Example1.rmp"));       
        IOContainer ioInput = new IOContainer();        
        IOContainer ioResult = myProcess.run(ioInput);
        // simple use 'ioResult' to display the results you want.       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are sure that

```
new RepositoryLocation("//C:/Users/
```

is a **valid** location? To me, it looks more like a typo.

However, you should maybe ask in the rapidminer forums; you are much more likely to talk to rapidminer experts there, than on a general-purpose programming site.

Comment: Anony-Mousse: Actually initially i gave the location like 'C:/...' but in the stack trace it was mentioned that the location should be like '//RepositoryLocation/path/to/file' so i changed it accordingly.

Comment: Well, just adding two slashes doesn't convert a path name into a repository, I guess.